# Re.match always returning None in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a very simple regex match ( the negation of all printable anscii characters other then '[' and ']'). [When I tested my pattern in regex pal](http://regexpal.com/) I got the matching that I wanted. Then I moved to my python unit test and my match never returns true

```
def testChatChars(string):
   return re.match('[^\x20-\x5A\x5C\x5E-\x7E]', string) is not None

print("testing Chat validation") 
print(testChatChars("") == False)
print(testChatChars("this is a valid chat message") == True)
print(testChatChars("9999abcdefghijklmnopqrxtuvxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP!@#$(^&*(&%$^^)*)!{},.;'\|?/7") == True )
print(testChatChars("this is not [ valid chat message") == False)
print(testChatChars("this is not ] valid chat message") == False)
print(testChatChars("9999abcdefghijklmnopqrxtuvxyz [][][[][]ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP!@#$(^&*(&%$^^)*)!{}[],.;'\|?/7ونِكود碼標準萬國") == False)
```

Which is returning

```
False //should be true
False //should be true
False //should be true
True
True
True
```

re.match is always returning none for some reason.

UPDATE:
[tried to change my code in the suggested fashion](http://ideone.com/7ch7oZ)
new output is

```
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def testChatChars(string):
   return re.match(r'[\x20-\x5A\x5C\x5E-\x7E]+$', string) is not None
```

Comment: This worked for me. Why do I not need a ^ character and what does the +$ symbol do?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins, I recommend you read http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html .

Comment: fair enough, I just made the (apparently wrong) assumption that python regex was perl regex.